# AJAX request to Laravel resource controller, best practice

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, get

I have set up a resource controller in Laravel with the following index function:

```
public function index()
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    $decks = Auth::user()->decks->sortByDesc('name');
    return view('decks.index')->with('decks', $decks);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

On a different page I also need the `$decks` variable via a AJAX call. Right now I have set up an additional route to my controller, from which I can retrieve the decks via a GET request:

```
public function getDecks()
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return;
    }
    $decks = Auth::user()->decks->sortByDesc('name');
    return response()->json($decks);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

**My question:** Is there a way to get the `$decks` variable via a request directly to `index` or is my solution the way to go?

If I make a get request to index I get the HTML of the decks.index view, but how can I access (if possible) the `$decks` variable?

I guess what I don't really grasp is this: What happens to `$decks` in the `->with('decks', $decks)` statement? I know I can then access `$decks` using blade syntax on that page, but from where does it access the data and can I also access it via AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not retrieve the `$decks` from the index route directly. When you call `view(..)->with(...)` it is internally passed to the blade template processor which also receives the `$decks` variable, the HTML is then build on the server-side and the 'compiled' HTMl is then returned to the browser. So once the server returns the result the `$decks` variable is not present anymore. Because of this behavior it is not possible to do what you want.

So yes, your solution is the way to go, although you might consider wrapping the `Auth::check()` in a `middleware` and move the call to `$decks` to a separate function in order to simplify your code.

I hope this answers your question, if anything is unclear feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You can return different results depending on what kind of request was done. There is no need for 2 routes:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $decks = Auth::user()->decks->sortByDesc('name');

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['decks' => $decks]);
    } else {
        return view('decks.index')->with('decks', $decks);
    }
}
```

@Sven Hakvoort is right, you should check for authentication in the route definition:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/decks', 'DecksController@index');
    // ... some other routes which requires authentication
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. However I would still not recommend this since the convention is that API's reside in dedicated API routes (for example, `host/api/v1/....`) and it would be bad practice to mix these. Therefore I would not recommend this approach, regardless of it being a working solution

Comment: @SvenHakvoort totally right, bu then, if you use 2 routes, you should also have a service to avoid code duplication..

Comment: Yes, definitely. I mentioned that short in my answer (however as a function, instead of a service). But that is definitely the best thing to do indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the proper way.  It is not typically a good idea to handle any business logic or data retrieval using your routes - using a controller is preferred, which is what you are doing.  If you want to avoid the `if (Auth::check())` statement in your controller, you could add the `auth` middleware directly to that route like this.

```
Route::get('example', 'YourController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

Regarding your question about `->with('decks', $decks)`:
That function is sending your `$decks` variable to the view to be rendered in the blade template.  That data is used by the server to render the page, and then the variable is discarded.  If you want to also be able to work with that data on your page using javascript, you could do something like this in your blade template.

```
<script>
    var decks = {!!$decks->toJSON()!!};
</script>
```

Comment: The OP is using a controller, notice the `index` function and the `getDecks` function, so that part of the answer is not valid ;)

Comment: And on a side note, he does not want to use the data in his JS on the page. the question is if he can ONLY retreive the JSON from that route

Comment: Yes, Sven is correct. I am sorry if my formulation of the question was misleading. But thank you for your remarks

Comment: I know OP is using a controller - isn't that what I said in my answer?  I was just giving an example of how to use middleware in the route.  Sorry if I misunderstood.  And yes, you are correct about the JS - I know that wasn't an exact answer to the question - just thought it might be helpful information - it not, sorry.